# How to change the extended property name

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, iextenderprovider

I have created a component and extended some properties for default controls with IExtenderProvider and it is working fine.

But the property name displays in the property grid like

> **PropertyName on myComponent1**

Is there any ways to change the property name so that i can simply show the extended property name alone?